# Проблемы с видением реализации подтверждения адреса электронной почты и восстановлением пароля

Tags: django-rest-framework

Я пишу API на DRF для того, чтобы впоследствии обращаться к нему и писать клиенты.
Появилась проблема с тем, чтобы корректно подобрать адрес, к которому приклеится uidb и токен. Если этот адрес будет в рамках проекта DRF, то пользователь напрямую обратится к API и ему информация будет преподнесена в формате REST.

Чтобы было яснее то, что я имею в виду, возьмем эндпоинт регистрации:
Пользователь на клиенте Android или iOS, а вообще без разницы, хоть веб, вводит в форму свои данные после чего они отправляются к API и там уже происходит их валидация, если все успешно, то осуществляется сохранение пользователя с неактивным статусом и отправка сообщения на его адрес электронной почты. Какая должна быть ссылка? Куда она должна вести? Я полагаю, что после открытия пользователем пришедшей ему ссылки ему должна отобразиться красивая надпись "Благодарим за подтверждение регистрации" или что-то в этом духе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите в сторону библиотек для подтверждения email для джанго, вот например [Django-Verify-Email](https://pypi.org/project/Django-Verify-Email/)

Comment: вопрос не об этом. сам функционал не проблема реализовать вручную. там делов то на две вьюхи, не вижу смысла подключать еще либу для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть разница, где сидит пользователь.
если в вебе, то обычная ссылка с http подойдет

если в андроиде, то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052512/how-to-open-an-installed-app-from-an-email-url-in-android
для иоса, то https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

можно, наверно, запоминать, что за приложение у пользователя и отправлять разные емайлы. можно отправлять все три. тут уже как захочется. так же и андроид и иос приложения умеют читать почту (отдельные разрешения). вариантов - много, выбирайте

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но вы немного не поняли. Передавая credentials, введенные в форму на клиенте API эндпоинту, осуществляющему регистрацию, который еще отправляет сообщение на почту с ссылкой. Вопрос в том, на какой адрес ее генерировать. Не напрямую к эндпоинту API же, который читает uidb и подтверждает пользователя?

Comment: но если есть веб, то есть сайт. туда ссылку и генерируйте. отдельная страница с "Спасибо, что присоединились". и не отправляйте uidb, создайте токен (просто случайный набор символов, хоть UUIDv4) перед отправкой письма, сохраните этот токен для пользователя в базе, а в ссылке используйте этот токен. и уже бекенд страницы сайта пусть проверяет, есть ли пользователь с таким токеном и активируйте его, если есть.

Comment: то есть API будет генерировать ссылку на клиент, чтобы пользователь перейдя по этой ссылке запустил процесс обращения к API? Это норм практика? И что насчет uidb? Почему не генерировать его? В исходниках сами создатели джанги генерят uidb и токен после чего получают юзера по uidb и чекают токен.

Comment: uidb, конечно, генерировать. не нужно передавать его в ссылке активации. это излишняя информация, как мне кажется. но можно отправлять и uidb и токен и сравнивать. так будет проще - не нужно индекс на токен, если у Вас токен хранится в SQL базе (его разумнее кидать в редис или мемкаш). 
Вы сами понимаете, что обращаться к апи из емайл клиента пользователя - странно, нужен переход на какую-то страницу, и там или бекенд обращается к апи для активации пользователя или можно фронтом (с андроид или иос приложениями по-другому можно сделать, я приводил примеры выше).

Comment: я добавил картинку в вопрос. возможно она сделана не совсем грамотно и аккуратно, но это то, как я вижу решение исходя из Ваших ответов. Это так?

Comment: да. именно все так

Comment: я прошу прощения, возможно это не касается вопроса, но куда забиндить этот самый адрес, на который будет генериться ссылка? Например, если я публикую код на DRF на гит и в другой репозиторий веб-клиент на Django и неизвестно будет на каком домене и конкретном роуте будет располагаться адрес подтверждения?

Comment: никак. нельзя достоверно узнать с сервера, какой адрес снаружи. может, тогда отказаться от ссылки? а код? который можно будет ввести в андроид-иос приложении или в вебе? тот же самый токен.

Comment: да, я думаю так даже удобнее будет. Ведь отсутствует конкретная привязка к вебу. Тогда каким образом генерить код и потом проверять, необходимый ли введен в форму или нет? Или Вы как раз и имели в виду, что в качестве него можно отправить токен и ожидать, когда юзер введет его?

Comment: отдельный ендпоинт - пришел токен, проверяется есть ли такой токен у неактивированного пользователя. если есть -  активируем - и все хорошо. ну тогда токен как иуд в4 неудобно уже. 8 символов например.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118107/discussion-between-crazy-theory-and-alexey-lakris).